# PHP Parse Error syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'

Tags: php, magento

I am facing the following error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'
```

The line of code throwing the error is:

```
$contents = str_replace(["\r\n","\r","\t","\n",'  ','    ','     '], '', $contents);
```

This PHP is within Magento 1.9. I am not familiar with PHP, so I wonder what this code is trying to do or why it would be throwing an error.

Comment: What PHP version are you running?

Comment: You could have Google'd the error, really.

Comment: I am running 5.6.33

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner thanks but I already did that. Although some things may come easier to you, I need a little more help on this topic.

Comment: either try escaping the brackets `str_replace(\["\r\n","\r","\t","\n",'  ','    ','     '\],` or remove them entirely `("\r\n","\r","\t","\n",'  ','    ','     ',` - at this point, it's hard to tell what you're really wanting to do here.

Answer (score 2):

Are you running this with a PHP version prior to 5.4? There did not know the short array syntax yet, so you have to write `array(\r\n","\r","\t","\n",'  ','    ','     ')` instead

Comment: You beat me to it

Comment: 5.6.33 is the version of PHP. Sorry for not including.

Comment: Technically, `array(\r\n"` is missing a double quote.

Comment: Yeah, lost that on copying...